# QT on windows - limitations, restrictions, commercial products

Tags: licensing, lgpl, commercial

I've downloaded the qt online installer from: https://www.qt.io/download-open-source to develop on Windows.

My question is: as long as we respect LGPL are we forced to buy a commercial license (for distribution of our client UI app or for development)?

Our product comes as a server deployment. We have a client UI application that ships with it offering an alternative to the web based configuration.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you can comply with the requirements of the applicable open source licenses, you don't need to buy a commercial license. The simple fact that your client software is deployed on Windows is not enough to need a commercial license.

Most Qt components are available under the LGPL license, but some of them are distributed under the GPL license.

Another reason for choosing the commercial license could be additional support that is offered with it.